# Иждивение, иждещи, иждену

Tags: этимология

Что это за странное поведение (чередование) согласных в старославянских глаголах иждивать (изживать), иждещи (изжечь) и иждену (изгнать)?

Приставка "из" перед звонкой корневой "ж" или "г" переходит в "иж" - ок.

А вот как корневое "ж" или "г" может перейти в "д"?

Есть ли в русском/старославянском ещё примеры чередования согласных ж->д или г->д?

Comment: хотя приставка там, всё же наверное "ис", тогда вопрос куда девается "с" и как корневая "г" может перейти в "жд"?

Comment: нашёл ещё такие "нестандартные" формы "изъждиву, изъждивенъ, изъждени" полагаю, что в представленных выше примерах приставочное "з" вылетает вовсе, но тогда получается, что старославянская "г" (гоить) может трансформировать как в "ж" (жить), так и в "жд" иждивение, а ещё и в "з" (друзи) в зависимости от окружающих её гласных. Кошмар!!!

Comment: @ присутствие нестандартных форм из предыдущего комментария, предполагаю объясняется наличием "ера" (твёрдого знака), из-за которого приставочная "з" и не отбрасывается

Comment: в пользу версии из второго комментария "г" переходит в "жд" изнемог -> изнемождение, получается что у "г" ряд чередования почти такой же как и у "д": "г","д" ->"ж"  -> "жд".

Comment: А может быть "д" и "г" это вообще одно и тоже? У "д" ведь тоже имеется гипотетическое чередование с "з" возить = водить, везти = вести 

Да они все и в алфавите располагаются, почитай, один за другим гдежз